# Excel formula to lookup blank value or maximum date time associated with a text value

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create an Excel formula that looks up a value (here, an animal type in column E) in a range (column B) and returns the latest associated date time value (column C) if there are no blanks associated with that value, and returns a blank if there are any blanks associated with that value. 
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcLFg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**My solutions:**

1. Count for the check up date of certain animal type is blank, if the count is greater than 0, then return "", otherwise, go to step 2.
2. find out the min value for certain animal type then return

For example, at Cell=E3 (assuming the data layout is same as the screenshot attached), type in below formula then hit '**Ctrl+Shift+Enter**'):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$13,E3,$C$3:$C$13,"")>0,"",MIN(IF($B$3:$B$13=E3,$C$3:$C$13)))
```